# Can someone tell me how to fix this Varnish error please?

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

Here's the error I get:

Message from VCC-compiler:

Unterminated string at

(input Line 39 Pos 19)

```
if (req.url ~ "^/[^?]+.(jpeg|jpg|png|gif|ico|js|css|txt|gz|
```

------------------#############################################

Running VCC-compiler failed, exit 1
VCL compilation failed

and here's the default.vcl

```
    backend default {
     .host = "localhost";
     .port = "8080";
}
acl purge {
        "localhost";
}
sub vcl_recv {
        if (req.request == "PURGE") {
                if (!client.ip ~ purge) {
                        error 405 "Not allowed.";
                }
                return(lookup);
        }
if (req.url ~ "^/$") {
               unset req.http.cookie;
            }
}
sub vcl_hit {
        if (req.request == "PURGE") {
                set obj.ttl = 0s;
                error 200 "Purged.";
        }
}
sub vcl_miss {
        if (req.request == "PURGE") {
                error 404 "Not in cache.";
        }
if (!(req.url ~ "wp-(login|admin)")) {
                        unset req.http.cookie;
                }
    if (req.url ~ "^/[^?]+.(jpeg|jpg|png|gif|ico|js|css|txt|gz|
zip|lzma|bz2|tgz|tbz|html|htm)(\?.|)$") {
       unset req.http.cookie;
       set req.url = regsub(req.url, "\?.$", "");
    }
    if (req.url ~ "^/$") {
       unset req.http.cookie;
    }
}
sub vcl_fetch {
        if (req.url ~ "^/$") {
                unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
        }
if (!(req.url ~ "wp-(login|admin)")) {
                        unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um, obviously you can't have a line break in the middle of the string. Move the tail end of the string up to the line it starts on, or have two different strings and concatenate them with +.

Comment: This is why I shouldn't multitask :)  Thanks.

Comment: You can, but you need to use the long string syntax described by HaxElit. That's how you get newlines into strings. Using it without this syntax used to work but then they broke it in 4.0.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a long string you can use {" Hello 
World
I'm 
long"}